# My wifi is not functioning properly on my HP 15-r249TU

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek-wireless

I only have Ubuntu on my laptop and my wifi is not working properly. It connects initially for 10 mins then either the connection is lost and doesn't connect to any network, or it stays connected but the net doesn't work. It works perfectly with ethernet. I have tried various wifi connections. I am an absolute ubuntu noob so please explain from the basic and in detail.
Thanks in advance
output of the command: lspci -knn | grep net -A2

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver this way

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```